# Are keyboard layout settings handled by two different applications in Xfce?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xfce, xkb

As seen in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/278982/47206), trying to make certain keyboard settings in Xfce I am faced by two separate options.

One is in Menu/Settings/Keyboards (`xfce4-keyboard-settings`) and displays this window:

[image]

The other is in the properties of the 'Keyboard Layouts' applet (`xfce4-xkb-plugin`) of the Xfce panel.

[image]

[image]

It seems that the settings made in the latter are the ones that count, while those of the former are pointless. (See linked answer for details.)

What to make out of this? - Is there potential conflict here? What to do?

---

I am in Quantal and Xfce, xfce4-panel 4.10.0, xfce4-settings 4.11, xfce4-xkb-plugin 0.5.4.3.

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/+bug/944468) filed with xkb-plugin seems to imply the opposite expected behavior as the two apps xfce4-keyboard-settings and xkb-plugin store their settings differently.

Comment: @maggotbrain - that issue on forgetting setting was common experience for me too, back in 11.10, but not in later versions of Ubuntu and Xfce (although  i assume it was xfce, not ubuntu specific). now, isn't *storring settings differently* the problem here? i'll make the same settings just to be sure; it looks like conflicting settings are possible but `xkb-plugin` overrides the `xfce4-keyboard-settings`, and the settings are remembered; somewhat confusing but working.

Comment: @maggotbrain - on that bug again: i found a similar one reported in a question here (http://askubuntu.com/q/66096/47206); my solution at the time was this (http://askubuntu.com/a/113517/47206), and worked; back then i switched to Lxde, and when came back to Xfce the problem was gone in newer versions; so my problem here seems to be different

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question?

Comment: @Seth - I do. Even if the answer is 'yes', I would like some details on that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simple answer is 'YES'.